# Window Capture with DXGI

Tags: c++, directx, dxgi, desktop-duplication

I have a working version of desktop capture using DXGI.
Is there a way to capture a separate window(HWND) using the same manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DXGI Desktop Duplication API offers you capture of parts of desktop. There is no option to capture specific window, but you have all the coordinates and so you can extract the window specific areas yourself (if and when they are not occluded, of course; if they are they do not have to be included into desktop composition in first place).